# FTP Server gives Error for uploading files with name of file in Chinese, Russian,Japanese text C#

Tags: c#, file, upload, ftp

I am facing an wiered error while uploading files to FTP server, The problem is only with files having file names in Russian,Chinese, Japanese, Portugese texts. On the other hand files with their file names in English text get uploaded successfully. I left no stone unturned to resolve this by pondering to different sources. I will pleased, If anyone knows the root cause behind this will help me with solution.

Regards 
Anand

Comment: It doesn't looks like C# client problem. More likely it's a problem on the FTP server side.

Comment: Which error does the server give?

Comment: @ Sanfor :  I get error stating {"The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."} when I start uploading file which has file name in Russian text

Comment: @ Andy  : Can you help me if their are any of settings I should make at server side or work around to overcome this problem